# Calculate the years and months it has been from a prescribed date from a table column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

I need to take the `purchasedate` from a table and calculate the total years plus the decimal equivalent of months left over from today's date and be able to present this calculated data in `yyy.mm`.

i.e 4.5 would be deciphered as 4 years and 6 months from `purchasedate`.

Answer (score 2):

If you work out the difference in months, then divide by 12 to get years, then use the remainder to get months which you can convert into a fraction e.g.

```
declare @PurchaseDate date = '01 Jan 2015', @Now date = current_timestamp

select convert(varchar(3),datediff(month,@PurchaseDate,@Now)/12) + '.' + substring(convert(varchar(5),convert(decimal(9,2),(datediff(month,@PurchaseDate,@Now)%12)/12.0)),3,2)
```

Gives

```
5.33
```

It might need some tweaking for edge cases.

Note the divide by `12.0` to force a fractional result - otherwise you just get an integer.

Comment: Dale K, Thanks so much for you help on this. It works great for what I needed. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just multiply by 12 and add months:

```
select dateadd(month, floor(@years * 12), purchasedate)
```